# Purpose of IsProductionMode in SPEAK

Tags: speak

While looking into the Sitecore Speak config files, I saw the following setting:

```
<!--  IS PRODUCTION MODE
      Indicates whether the system is in production mode or not.
      Default: false
-->      
<setting name="IsProductionMode" value="false" />
```

I have searched the internet but did not find any useful documentation of its purpose. I have also check the code in the `Sitecore.Speak.ItemWebApi.dll` but it seems that there are not usage of it. So, my question is as follows:

1. What is the purpose of `IsProductionMode`?
2. Is it still in use?

Sitecore Version: 8.2 U-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the  Sitecore.Configuration.SpeakSettings I found:

```
public static bool IsProductionMode
{
  get
  {
    return Settings.GetBoolSetting("IsProductionMode", false);
  }
}
```

and above propery is used in :

```
 // Sitecore.Shell.SettingsHost
 public virtual bool IsProductionMode
{
  get
  {
     return SpeakSettings.IsProductionMode;
  }
}
```

But anywhere in the code is not used this property;

This particular setting is not used by any code at this time and has no effect. It may just be a leftover from an earlier stage of the project.
You can can simply ignore it.

Comment: It is likely, this property is mocked and overridden in unreleased unit testing code.

Comment: Did you search the JS files in /Sitecore/* just to make sure its not used in the Javascript somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. It might be using is future releases or it has been deprecated